# What lemmatizer can i use for arabic text using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, stanford-nlp, text-processing

How can I get lemmas for Arabic words? I tried the ISRI Arabic Stemmer from NLTK but it returns roots of words:

```
from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer
st = ISRIStemmer()
print st.stem(u'اعلاميون')
```

It returns the root `علم` and i want the lemma `اعلامي`

Answer (score 5):

The state-of-the-art is [Farasa Lemmatizer](https://farasa.qcri.org/lemmatization/).

Farasa Lemmatizer outperforms MADAMIRA Lemmatizer based on accuracy. It gives  +7% relative gain in accuracy above MADAMIRA in lemmatization task.

You can read more about Farasa Lemmatizer from the following link:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06700.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The only lemmatization software for Arabic I am aware of is the MADAMIRA, made by Columbia University. You can use the online interface at this URL: http://nlp.ldeo.columbia.edu/madamira/

Answer (score 0):

```
print(ISRIStemmer().suf32("اعلاميون"))
```

> 'اعلامي'

For more information, please see the [ISRIStemmer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html?highlight=lemmatizer) documentation

Comment: Do I have to specify the suf32 and customize it for each different word?
I didn't quite understand what the suf32  does exactly. Thanks!